# Non functioning cogs | DiscordPy 2.0

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like to use the cog to make my code cleaner but my cog "ping" does not want to work. The bot goes online but on my discord server I can't find my slash command.
Thanks for your help!

My code :

- File main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//", intents = discord.Intents.all())
bot.load_extension("cogs.ping")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"{bot.user} is online !")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

- File ping.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands



class Ping(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.command()
  async def ping(self, ctx):
    ctx.send(f"Pong in {self.latency * 1000}ms")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

My hierarchy :

- mybot

  - main.py
  - cogs

    - ping.py

Answer (score 3):

Extension loading is now async, as the error message (that you should be getting, but didn't include in the post) suggests.

Migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

> on my discord server I can't find my slash command

PS there are no slash commands here, your `ping` is a regular message command. Even after loading the cog there won't be any slash commands, because you didn't make any.