# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found

Tags: python, discord.py

ok so i was making a discord music bot and i have this problem, the bot don't use the commands that i write in the code help me please :c

**main.py**

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs=[music]

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="?",intents=
discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)


client.run("TOKEN")
```

**music.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client=client

    @commands.command(name="join")
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("No hay nadie conectado pavo qlo")
        voice_channel=ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command(name="disconnect")
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command(name="play")
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS={'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS={'format':'bestaudio'}
        vc=ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info=ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2=info['formats'][0]['url']
            source=await discord.FFmpegPCMAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command(name="pause")
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client.pause():
            await ctx.send("Paused ⏸️")

    @commands.command(name="resume")
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client.resume():
            await ctx.send("Resume ▶")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

i don't know what i suppose to fix in the code

Comment: Cog loading is async, your code is not. Also, use `load_extension` instead of manually calling the `setup` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non functioning cogs | DiscordPy 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74944802/non-functioning-cogs-discordpy-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

So you need to load the extension like this

## main.py

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands


cogs = ["music"]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?",intents=
discord.Intents.all())

for cog in cogs:
    client.load_extension(cog)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

The `commands.Bot` instance has a `load_extension` method that is able to load a python module, and get the cogs.

## Note

Place the `music.py` module in a package called `cogs`. Each cog goes in the `cogs` package.

```
├── cogs
│   └── music.py
└── main.py
```

Then you are able to keep things more organised using this code:

## main.py

```py
cogs = ("music",)


class MusicPlayer(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="?", intents=discord.Intents.all())


    async def ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()

        try:
            for cog in cogs:
                self.load_extension(f"cogs.{cog}")
        except Exception as e:
            print('*[CLIENT][LOADING_EXTENSION][STATUS] ERROR ', e)
        else:
            print('*[CLIENT][LOADING_EXTENSION][STATUS] SUCCESS')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MusicPlayer().run("TOKEN")
```